# can you interpret varargs as an array if they are all pointers of the same type?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

In case you have `int foo(a_type first, ...)`, where the varargs are all `const char *` (or some other pointer type) and you can determine their number from  `first` (or by a terminating `NULL` pointer), can you somehow interpret this structure as an array (`const char **`) with no need to `malloc` an actual array and copy the pointers into it? Shouldn't the arguments be properly aligned on the stack like if they where in an array? Would that be portable or can e.g. the order of the arguments be different?

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I didn't plan to use anything like that in production code. I just was curious.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers (like your "`const char **`"). If you can't wrap your head around this simple fact, you probably shouldn't be trying to attribute any particular layout to varargs arguments.

Comment: @KerrekSB What are you trolling about? In C arrays are memory areas of a multiple of size of the type of the elements. The array itself is passed as a pointer to a function and can be referred to via a pointer  in any case. Why do I need to explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get away with it. For a while.

The problem is that in C you can get away with a lot of things in Undefined Behavior, but that does not make them correct.

One problem with your idea is that C does not require the computer to have anything called a "stack" or to put function arguments on it. They aren't required to be in any particular location or order.

Comment: Don't force varargs the use of the stack (instead of call via registers)? But yes, it's just a hacky idea. Not really serious.

Comment: @panzi: C is very generic. It does not require that a computer have a stack or registers in order to implement C.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not be portable. As far as the language standard is concerned, you must use the varargs functions and macros to access the variable arguments, and there is no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

No; there's no guarantee that the variable argument list will be laid out contiguously, so you can't assume that your values will be laid as as though they were in an array.  You must use the `va_*` macros to advance through the list.